# Determine Featured Image Size in header

Tags: themes

I was using thumbnails of 192 pixels square but want to change the size to 235 pixels, the Regenerate Thumbnail plugin does not upsize so since I want thumbnails above 200 pixels to use the Twitter Card with Large Image. I also don't want to manually replace all my old thumbnails (Featured Images) with larger ones, but I thought I could use some code to detect newer larger Featured Images which I plan to use, but I can not access the Featured Image inside the Header as it is not in the Loop correct?

Comment: You would be correct, you'd need to figure out what the current post was, but there are ways to do that

Comment: Can you post me to a technique to do that?

Comment: There are a number of questions on this site asking exactly that, you should look them up :)

Comment: I did search, from what I can tell, what I want to do isn't really feasible. I've published over a 1000 posts and just going back and adding featured images and custom excerpts and tags has been a lot of work, redoing it with larger featured images appears to be a manual process and without an image over 200 pixels you can't use the Twitter Card with Large Image, my blog just isn't that popular, probably not worth all the work I've put into it.

Comment: "get current post outside of loop" got me plenty of results on google

Comment: I'll look again but the images uploaded into the system will never be bigger than 200 pixels unless I replace them so I'm happy not having a Twitter Card that didn't exist when I started my blog. Twitter didn't exist when I started my blog. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

well your question is a bit confusing because you say you had 192px "Thumbnails" assuming you mean the_post_thumbnail then the actual original image size that you uploaded originally could and would most likely be larger, in which case the regenerate thumbnail plugin would work for you.

when you say you can not access featured images inside the header as it not in the loop this is also confusing because if it is already using smaller featured images this is misleading.

that being said, you could potentially move the portion of the post that contains the featured image out of the header and into the single page template.

Sorry this should probably be a comment, in short if you can provide more info a solution should be available.

Comment: The original image is 192 pixels I cleverly sized every single one perfectly. WordPress is very popular, but it has grown so much, but it was originally just a blogging platform. I've been using it for ten years, a clever person than me might have some jquery magic, but I think I will have to live without perfection, my blog is just too old and too big.